# how good is the rest support in symfony php framework?

Tags: php, rest, symfony1

I am making a REST based web server in PHP and wanted to know if using symfony would be a good idea.

Comment: Which one - Symfony 1.2 or the new 2.0?

Comment: unless you specify hard criteria for "good", this is not constructive.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this even a question? What requirements do you have? Do you need security, speed, low memory usage, caching, maintainability, rapid development, testability? In what order? Why do you need a framework at all? Why PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony 2.0 is a very good framework with a component architecture that makes it easy to use only the parts you need. The website [symfpony-project.org](http://symfpony-project.org/) describes how to create a REST web service with Symfony 2 (and compres it to Symfony 1).

Esspeciialy the HTTP kernel and routing components of Symfony 2 give me the impression that you can do a REST service easily: The Request objects contain alls kinds of useful information on the request headers and method. The routing component makes it easy to wire your controllers to certain URL patterns.

If the whole framework is too overwhelming for you, have a look at the [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) microframework. It is based on Symfony components and is good for quickly whipping up a REST web service.

Answer (score -3):

Using the latest version of symfony would be a great choice

Comment: How would it be a great choice? What features does it offer? What are its advantages over other possible frameworks?

Comment: What a misleading answer. Without requirements, no one can say what would be a good or bad choice.